# MS Access VBA code not deleteing all records

Tags: mysql, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to delete all the records of one table that appear in another, however it only seems to delete some of the records.

```
Private Sub removeDuplicates()

Dim resultSet1 As DAO.Recordset

Set resultSet1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("remove")
resultSet1.MoveFirst

Do Until resultSet1.EOF

    Dim sql As String
    sql = "Delete * from [Copy Of remove] Where"

    If Not IsNull(resultSet1.Fields(0)) And (resultSet1.Fields(0) <> "") Then
    sql = sql & " PHN = """ & resultSet1.Fields("PHN") & """"
    End If

    If Not IsNull(resultSet1.Fields(1)) And (resultSet1.Fields(1) <> "") Then
    sql = sql & " and Year = " & resultSet1.Fields(1)
    End If

    If Not IsNull(resultSet1.Fields(2)) And (resultSet1.Fields(2) <> "") Then
    sql = sql & " and [Date of Referral to Thoracics] = " & resultSet1.Fields(2)
    End If

    If Not IsNull(resultSet1.Fields(3)) And (resultSet1.Fields(3) <> "") Then
    sql = sql & " and [Date of Thoracics Consult] = " & resultSet1.Fields(3)
    End If

    If Not IsNull(resultSet1.Fields(4)) And (resultSet1.Fields(4) <> "") Then
    sql = sql & " and [Date Thoracic Surgery Booked] = " & resultSet1.Fields(4)
    End If

    If Not IsNull(resultSet1.Fields(5)) And (resultSet1.Fields(5) <> "") Then
    sql = sql & " and [Date of Thoracic Surgery] = " & resultSet1.Fields(5)
    End If

    If Not IsNull(resultSet1.Fields(6)) And (resultSet1.Fields(6) <> "") Then
    sql = sql & " and [Study Group] = """ & resultSet1.Fields(6) & """"
    End If

    If Not IsNull(resultSet1.Fields(7)) And (resultSet1.Fields(7) <> "") Then
    sql = sql & " and [Access Method] = """ & resultSet1.Fields(7) & """"
    End If

    If Not IsNull(resultSet1.Fields(8)) And (resultSet1.Fields(8) <> "") Then
    sql = sql & " and Procedure = """ & resultSet1.Fields(8) & """"
    End If

    If Not IsNull(resultSet1.Fields(9)) And (resultSet1.Fields(9) <> "") Then
    sql = sql & " and Site = """ & resultSet1.Fields(9) & """"
    End If

    If Not IsNull(resultSet1.Fields(10)) And (resultSet1.Fields(10) <> "") Then
    sql = sql & " and [Procedure 2] = """ & resultSet1.Fields(10) & """"
    End If

    If Not IsNull(resultSet1.Fields(11)) And (resultSet1.Fields(11) <> "") Then
    sql = sql & " and [Site 2] = """ & resultSet1.Fields(11) & """"
    End If

    If Not IsNull(resultSet1.Fields(12)) And (resultSet1.Fields(12) <> "") Then
    sql = sql & " and [Primary site] = """ & resultSet1.Fields(12) & """"
    End If

    If Not IsNull(resultSet1.Fields(13)) And (resultSet1.Fields(13) <> "") Then
    sql = sql & " and Grade = """ & resultSet1.Fields(13) & """"
    End If

    If Not IsNull(resultSet1.Fields(14)) And (resultSet1.Fields(14) <> "") Then
    sql = sql & " and [T Stage] = """ & resultSet1.Fields(14) & """"
    End If

    If Not IsNull(resultSet1.Fields(15)) And (resultSet1.Fields(15) <> "") Then
    sql = sql & " and [N Stage] = """ & resultSet1.Fields(15) & """"
    End If

    If Not IsNull(resultSet1.Fields(16)) And (resultSet1.Fields(16) <> "") Then
    sql = sql & " and [M Stage] = """ & resultSet1.Fields(16) & """"
    End If

    If Not IsNull(resultSet1.Fields(17)) And (resultSet1.Fields(17) <> "") Then
    sql = sql & " and [Same Staging?] = """ & resultSet1.Fields(17) & """"
    End If

    CurrentDb.Execute sql

    resultSet1.MoveNext
Loop

resultSet1.Close
End Sub
```

This is the code I'm using, to test if it works I've been using the table *remove* and *Copy Of Remove* but only about 20 of the 135 records are being deleted even though one is a copy of the other.

Also I match all fields when creating the delete query and I have a feeling this is where the issue is coming from.

P.S.
Option explicit and option compare database are declared above this sub

Comment: so what does `sql` look like when all of that string building is completed? have you tried running that query manually yourself?

Comment: Just a guess (when I was working in VBA I always used ADODB over an ODBC connection) but have you tried bracketing all the fields; I wouldn't be surprised if `Year` caused some weird behavior.

Comment: The delete statement looks like 'Delete * from [Copy Of remove] Where PHN = "123456789" and year = 2012 and [Date Thoracic Surgery Booked] = 6/5/2013' @MarcB

Comment: there you go. `6/5/2013` isn't quoted, so it's seen as a division operation. you're doing `[Date ...] = 0.0005961etc...`

Comment: That works! thank you very much, but it need to be of the form `#6/5/2013#` if you could post your answer so i could give you the props you deserved @MarcB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't quoted your date value, so you're doing a division operation:

```
DELETE ... WHERE [Date...] = 6/5/2013
which becomes
DELETE ... WHERE [Date...] = 0.0005961etc...
```

Try

```
DELETE ... WHERE [Date...] = #6/5/2013#
                             ^--------^
```

instead.